# Passar um objeto para um modal Bootstrap

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, modal

Preciso passar um objeto do banco de dados para um modal quando abro ele para mostrar as informações do objeto.

É possível fazer isso? segue o cshtml da view em que o botão do modal é chamado, ele abre corretamente mas não consigo passar as informações do objeto para mostrar nele.

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="feature-box col-sm-2">
            <ul class="list-group" >
                <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">
                    <h5><strong> Sala: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome)</strong></h5>
                    <button id="btnReservar" type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#mySala">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        Reservar
                    </button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
     }
```

Meu Modal definido, ainda sem as informações.

```
    <div id ="mySala" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                   <h4 class="modal-title">Sala</h4>
                   </div>
                   <div class="modal-body"><p>Insereir as informações &hellip;</p></div>
                   <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Como posso fazer para passar o objeto item assim como eu uso no button, em :

```
     <h5><strong> Sala: @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome)</strong></h5>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consigo enxergar 2 caminhos que pode seguir:

1 - Utilizar o atributo data do HTML5 para passar os dados para o modal, via JSON, como ex. `data-meu-atributo="{valor:1, valor2:2}`.

2 - Utilizar uma chamada Ajax no callback do evento `open` do modal, como no ex:

```
  $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        /*chamada ajax aqui ..*/
    });
```